# Center panel scroll in control C#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, center

I have a `Panel` in which i'm adding controls to it dynamically. I want to scroll the `Panel` to the position of one given control of the `Panel`

I'm using the `ScrollControlIntoView` method of the `ScrollableControl` object as follows:

```
public void centerPanel(Control p){
        panel.ScrollControlIntoView(p);
    }
```

But the panel seems to move to random positions.

The `AutoScroll`property is set to `True` in the `Panel`.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

I have detected my mistake. I was scrolling the `Panel` before adding the `Control` to the `Panel`.

So, here is the correct way to scroll a `Panel`to a given control.

```
panel.Controls.Add(control);
panel.ScrollControlIntoView(control);
```

Thanks.